# Get Object XmlDocument value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, file-upload

I'm executing an ajax call to a external api (this cannot be modified) to upload an store a file into a folder. This request must return a path (ex. "C:\Doctos\File.pdf" but after a console.log is returning something like this:

> #document < string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">"C:\Doctos\File.pdf"

So my question is, what can I do to get only the text that I want without any change in the api (because I'm not able to do it).

Here is the ajax call that I'm using.

**PD. This ajax call is using the provided structure for the dev team that developed the api so things like dataType also cannot be modified**

```
var data = new FormData();
var files = $('#fileUpload').get(0).files;

if (files.length > 0) {
    data.append("UploadedFile", files[0]);
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'api/v1/moreurl/UploadFile',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        var res = data;
        //Returns above example
        console.log(res);

        //Returns something like <p>[object XMLDocument]</p>
        $('#MyInput').attr('src', res);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use regular expressions to get the desired string from received data. Put this after `success` line.

```
var regex = />\"(.*)\"/;
var matched = regex.exec(data);
var result = matched[1];
console.log(result);
```

The regex matches the last quoted string in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data in the xml with jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'api/v1/moreurl/UploadFile',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        // Get the contents of the xml
        var file = $(data).find('string').text();
        $('#MyInput').attr('src', file);
    }
});
```